# Rails Routes: Missing the 'id' in feed routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem defining my rails routes.

I have this route:

```
     resource :feeds, only: [:edit, :destroy] do
      member do
        post 'insert_record'
        delete 'delete_record'
      end
      collection do
        post 'reorder'
      end
    end
```

And this route

```
     resources :brands do
      member do
        delete 'destroy_contact'
      end
      collection do
        get 'list', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
      end
    end
```

Why in the first case the routes generated are:

```
GET    /admin/feeds(.:format)          admin/feeds#show
PATCH  /admin/feeds(.:format)          admin/feeds#update
PUT    /admin/feeds(.:format)          admin/feeds#update
DELETE /admin/feeds(.:format)          admin/feeds#destroy
```

And for brands

```
GET    /admin/brands/:id(.:format)   admin/brands#show
PATCH  /admin/brands/:id(.:format)   admin/brands#update
PUT    /admin/brands/:id(.:format)   admin/brands#update
DELETE /admin/brands/:id(.:format)   admin/brands#destroy
```

Why I lose the "id" on feeds? I must add a route to delete a single feed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `resource` keyword in the case of feeds is singular, while the `resources` keyword is plural in the case of brands.

Rails has this concept of [Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) to define routes for resources that are found not through an `id` param, but something else, or simply don't make sense to have an `id` in their route. The guides give the simplest example of a `/profile` route that always shows the currently logged in user.